# Finding mysql entries from different timezones

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am creating an application that needs to work in different timezones. Since I don't have access to the server config, I need to convert all of my timestamps during queries. I would generally set all dates to UTC and then figure out the offset by that, but I just don't have access to that right now.

I'm currently trying to query for data ONLY from the past day. I don't care about the past 24 hours, I only care about if the data was in the past day only.

Here is an example of one of my query that I need help with:

```
SELECT
count(u.id) as total_count, uf.user_id, uf.friend_id, u.username, u.image_location, u.phone, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email, MAX(us.created_at) as created_at, u.updated_at FROM users_friends uf 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = uf.friend_id 
LEFT JOIN users_streams us ON u.id = us.user_id 
WHERE uf.user_id = 1 AND uf.status != "BLOCKED" AND us.status = "ACTIVE" AND CONVERT_TZ(us.created_at, "America/Los_Angeles", "America/Los_Angeles") >= DATE_ADD(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(), "America/Los_Angeles", "America/Los_Angeles"), INTERVAL -0 DAY) AND uf.user_id = 1 
GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY us.created_at DESC
```

As you can see, I'm converting my date of creation from Los Angeles (server time) to Los Angeles... Which works perfectly. When other countries come in.. For example Asia/Shanghai, I notice that it's still pulling data. I believe its because I need to round up to the nearest day?

My issue is that when I try to run the same query but do `CONVERT_TZ(us.created_at, "America/Los_Angeles", "Asia/Shanghai")` I'm still getting results from the previous day.

How can I make it so no matter what timezone I'm converting to, It will only pull data from the current day and ignore data from anything after the new day has began (12:00 AM).

Comment: Do you change the destination timezone in both `convert_tz` functions?

Comment: Yes i do change them. I think the issue is that the timezone is using CURDATE instead of NOW(). Should I convert convert_tz(NOW), X, X)?

Comment: No, the issue is that you change the destination in both `convert_tz` functions. If you first compare `a > b` (both times Los Angeles) and then `a - 10 > b - 10` (both timezones changed), you will get exactly the same rows.

Comment: Well that example is just a sample of the code i'm working with. In my script it's actually comparing los angeles and shanghai china

Comment: I'm not sure if you got me. You have 4 times `Los Angeles` in your query. Just replace 1 of them with `Shanghai`, not 2. Or you can just write `... AND us.created_at >= CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(), "America/Los_Angeles", "Asia/Shanghai") AND ...`  or `... AND us.created_at >= CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(), "Asia/Shanghai", "America/Los_Angeles") AND ...` depending on your direction.